# Setting the Default Luminosity for a ColorDialog

Tags: c#, winforms, color-picker

I'm creating a `ColourDialog` and I've set the default colour that I want it to show, but I can't seem to set the hue, saturation, or luminosity.

```
Color colour = (Color)value;
ColorDialog dlg = new ColorDialog();
dlg.Color = colour;
```

Is there an option to change those three options? I mainly want to know to make it easier to use by ensuring the luminosity is always set to 120 (otherwise the user has to change it because white and black force the luminosity to 240).

Comment: I don't think so. You can write your own dialog or change the chosen color afterwards to have the luminosity you want.

Answer (score 0):

The default Color class does not provide an option to change the HSL values.
However, you can make use of [P/Invoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shlwapi.colorrgbtohls) here to easily convert them:

```
[DllImport("shlwapi.dll")]
static extern void ColorRGBToHLS(int RGB, ref int H, ref int L, ref int S);

static public void ColorToHLS(Color C, ref int H, ref int L, ref int S)
{
  ColorRGBToHLS(ColorTranslator.ToWin32(C), ref H, ref L, ref S);
}

[DllImport("shlwapi.dll")]
static extern int ColorHLSToRGB(int H, int L, int S);

static public Color HLSToColor(int H, int L, int S)
{
  return ColorTranslator.FromWin32(ColorHLSToRGB(H, L, S));
}
```

The usage would then be something along the lines of:

```
Color colour = (Color)value;
ColorDialog dlg = new ColorDialog();

int H, L, S = 0;
ColorToHLS(colour, H, L, S);

L = 120;

colour = HLSToColor(H, L, S);  

dlg.Color = colour;
```

Briefly explained: you convert your color to HLS, change the luminosity to 120 (or whatever you want) and convert it back to a color.